# Error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)" from the command prompt but not from Visual Studio

Tags: c++, windows, dll, cmake

I have a project that I build with CMake, which is composed of a library `black.dll` and an executable `black.exe` that depends on the DLL. The DLL in turn depends on `libz3.dll` which is an external dependency.

When I build from the command prompt using CMake I cannot run the executable because of the error "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000142)". The external dependency `libz3.dll` is correctly copied into the executable directory.

But, when I build the project from Visual Studio 2019 (making it use CMake under the hood as well), everything works properly (when I copy `libz3.dll` into the executable directory).

I've looked at the two executables with Dependency Walker to understand what's the different between the two but there are no differences (*both* show errors of missing strange libraries such as `API-MS-WIN-CRT-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL` but in the case of the executable built with VS it seems to not be a problem).

I've also checked to be building for the correct architecture: both the executable, the library and `libz3.dll` are built for x64.

What can I check to understand what's going on?

Comment: "When I build from the command prompt using CMake" - Even when build from the command prompt, CMake requires a [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) for build the project. Do you use `Visual Studio 16 2019` generator?

Comment: Yes, I use that generator. And then I compile with `cmake --build .` which invokes `msbuild`

Comment: You provide too little information for being able to suggest something specific. Try to eliminate dependencies from your project, one by one. After each elimination try to build and run executable. That way you could find which dependency causes the problem.

Comment: I do not have any dependencies to remove besides `libz3.dll` which is not possible to remove. What other causes can that error have?

Comment: Iirc windows looks for dlls in the current working directory or in the `PATH` environment variable, so this could just be a case of calling the program with the wrong working directory.

Comment: It's not a problem of how the program is called, because if I call from the command prompt the executable built with VS, it works.

Comment: I think the same as @fabian thinks.

Comment: I call the two executables in the same way. Both have the dependencies in their own directories. One works, one doesn't.

Comment: I've managed to compile the project without the dependency on `libz3.dll`, and it works. So the problem is how I get the dependency to work. There's something in how VS compiles the project that differs from `msbuild`, that cause the library to be linked somehow differently.

Comment: I've found the problem. There's seems to be a bug in CMake's Visual Studio generator. I've noticed that VS used the Ninja generator and tried on the command line and it worked. I do not have any idea of what is happening under the hood but now it works.